# Plotting vertical lines for every point on x-axis and adding them

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to generate a plot like 'fig-A'. I am a new user of Latex. So, i tried to find code on lines but I got the nearest one look like 'fig-B', which is not the one I am looking for.

here is the data:

```
x   t
1   1
4   2
5   3
1   4
6   5 
3   6
4   7
4   8
```

Basically what I want is to draw a vertical line at 't1' whose length will be 'x1' and then another vertical line at 't2', whose length will be 'x2' but this line will start from (x1 - t2).

I tried with this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot+[const plot mark right]
coordinates
{(0,3)    (2,5)  (4,3)   (5,7)
 (7,5) (8,4)  (9,5)  (10,2)
 (11,7) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

but obviously this is something else. can anyone suggest what to do? thanks. [image]

The plot is for unfinished work.

Comment: You simply can draw a single line joining the points: `\draw ( , ) -- ( , ) -- ( , ) .......... ( , );` Just insert the coordinates.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand this correctly: With the data in the table, you would want to draw a sequence of lines `(6,0) -- (6,1) -- (3,-2) -- (3,2) -- (5,1) -- (5,6)`?

Comment: @jake: yap, sequence of line, connected.

Comment: @SakilChowdhury: But unlike the "fig-B" in your question, the x coordinates are not monotonically increasing, rather the plot goes back and forth across the x axis, correct?

Comment: @jake, actually, i can fix the coordinates once i know how to plot 'vertical lines' at evey 't' point and how to connect them.

Comment: @SakilChowdhury: I'm not sure what you mean by "fix the coordinates". Maybe you could edit your question to include an example of the type of input data you want to use and a mock-up (a drawing) of the desired output corresponding to that input data. That might be easier to understand.

Comment: @jake ,thank u for replying. I have edited my data. say: at t1 = 1, i want to draw a 'vertical line' parallel to y-axis(length x1 = 1), then at t2= 2, there will be another vertical line of length x2  =4, but this line will start from the point (y-axis: x1-t2, x-axis: t2). and then connect the two vertical lines and so on. i hope this makes things clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the "corners" to the coordinate list may not be elegant, but it will get the job done.  I assume you only want the original data points marked.

[image: sawtooth plot]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot[only marks,color=blue]
coordinates
{(1,1) (2,4) (3,5) (4,1) (5,6) (6,3) (7,4) (8,4)};
\addplot[no markers,color=blue]
coordinates
{(1,0) (1,1) (2,0) (2,4) (3,0) (3,5) (4,0) (4,1) (5,0) (5,6) (6,0) (6,3) (7,0) (7,4) (8,0) (8,4)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```